# Symfony2 | Hide/remove Header From response/forward

Tags: symfony, header, hide, response, forward

I'm trying to put 2 Controller result in one controller, so I forward in the first one using `'$response = $this->forward('Bundle:Controller:functionXXX');`'.

in thecontroller ' `functionXXXAction`' I return response using renderView.

The problem is that the **forward function return this header** in the top of the page:

```
"HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 09:56:50 GMT"
```

Any solution to hide it from the page?!

Comment: Why do you want to combine the results from two controllers? Maybe you can move the logical stuff into services and then use only one controller, which calls both services and combine the result of them.

Comment: Thanks you for your answers, I use two controllers instead of service to be able to use as a web service for ajax request...

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit old but maybe someone will be looking for an answer in the future. To get rid of the header you just need to call:
$response = $this->forward('Bundle:Controller:functionXXX');
**$response->getContent();**